# Amending TFS Task State - Exception TF26212

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, exception, tfs, workitem

**Overview**
I have created a program to override states within a Team Foundation Server task, for example: Change a bug's state from 'New' to 'Done' or vice versa.

I can currently collect to the TFS Store and have the ability to amend fields such as projected delivery but when it comes to overriding the state, I receive the following exception:

**ServerRejectedChangesException was unhandled -** 
TF26212: Team Foundation Server could not save your changes. There may be problems with the work item type definition, or a conflicting work item type definition change may require a refresh on your client. Restart your client application and try again, or contact your Team Foundation Server administrator.

**Note & Things I have tried**
- this functionality of amending the States works on another users machine but for some reason not on mine. I am already a member of the group 'Project Collection Administrator' and have the majority of administrator rights to my knowledge, I have also used the reference to WorkItemStoreFlags.BypassRules.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure the State transition you are attempting to make is a valid transition.  Work Item Types in TFS define specific transitions allowed between states.  Not every state can be transitioned to from others.  For example, it may enforce that the states go New->Approved->In Progress, there may not be a transition defined for New->In Progress directly.

If you tried to update the state on a WI from New directly to In Progress I imagine you would get an error similar to the one you posted.

Comment: Thanks for your response, I am aware that these may be invalid transitions but this is the aim of my application, to override the states and using the BypassRules should make this work. Like I said, it works on another users computer but not mine unfortunately.